# How can I set the background color of individual cells in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and I'm trying to change cell backgrounds based on the content of the cell. For example, if a cell's value is `5`, then the cell's background should be blue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [CellPainting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting.aspx) event to check each cell's content and paint different background colors.